# How to set helix toolkit camera target

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

How can I set the camera target and zoom to the target ?
I have many 3d Visuals with Point3D positions which of course are
transformed so the camera doens't locate the object acurately.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Used CameraController property to Set Camera in a HelixViewport3D

```
HelixViewport3D HelixViewport3d_1 = new HelixViewport3D();
// after Add objects to HelixViewport3d_1 then set camera...
//...
//...
//set Camera
HelixViewport3d_1.CameraController.CameraUpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1); // set CameraUpDirection property is optional to have better view !! :)
HelixViewport3d_1.CameraController.CameraTarget = new Point3D(30, 0, 0); // or your Target Object 3D Coordinate
HelixViewport3d_1.CameraController.AddZoomForce(-0.3); // amount of Zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer by `user4106274`:
Here the `AddZoomForce()` is method set to -0.3 for zoom, because the Target object was in (+x,+y,+Z) locations, and perhaps the `CameraLookDirection` property was in a contrary location.

In different `CameraLookDirection` property we should Zoom by:
    `HelixViewport3d_1.CameraController.AddZoomForce(+0.3); // amount of Zoom`